# SwiftUI table with column of checkboxes not updating the correct table entry on sort

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm new to swift and swiftUI so I'm still struggling with understanding bindings.

I have written this example with a table with a column of checkboxes, and a sort which allows you to sort by whether the checkbox is ticked or not.

Initially, I was using UUID() for the id, which would be preferred, but I couldn't get this example to work with that id for updating the correct value. So instead, I made this hacky attempt which sets the id to the index and then directly changes that. However, it has led to some odd behaviour so when you sort the checkboxes don't remain with the right person.

Can someone please help explain where I've gone wrong? Thank you

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    struct Person: Identifiable {
        var id: Int
        var name: String
        var checkedIn: Bool
    }
    
    @State var people = [Person(id: 0, name: "George", checkedIn: false),
                         Person(id: 1, name: "Leah", checkedIn: true),
                         Person(id: 2, name: "Sarah", checkedIn: false)]
    
    @State private var selected = Set<Person.ID>()

    @State private var sortOrder = [KeyPathComparator(\Person.name)]

    
    private struct BoolComparator: SortComparator {
        typealias Compared = Bool

        func compare(_ lhs: Bool, _ rhs: Bool) -> ComparisonResult {
            switch (lhs, rhs) {
            case (true, false):
                return order == .forward ? .orderedDescending : .orderedAscending
            case (false, true):
                return order == .forward ? .orderedAscending : .orderedDescending
            default: return .orderedSame
            }
        }

        var order: SortOrder = .forward
    }

    
    var body: some View {
        Table(people, selection: $selected, sortOrder: $sortOrder) {
            TableColumn("Name", value: \.name)
            TableColumn("Checked In", value: \.checkedIn, comparator: BoolComparator()) { person in
                Toggle("Checked In", isOn: $people[person.id].checkedIn)
                    .labelsHidden()
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: sortOrder) { newOrder in
            people.sort(using: newOrder)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorting the array mixes up the indexes, this cannot work. The `BoolComparator` looks like it comes from the Apple sample project GardenApp. In this code the Toggle is connected to a `Binding` which uses a custom `id` subscription.

Comment: @vadian okay thank you. Yes, it is from GardenApp. If I change my Person struct so it uses ```let id = UUID()``` how do I then create a binding and connect it to the toggle? I've tried to change the comparator but am struggling to find any guidance

Comment: The comparator is fine. Look into the original code, the garden items are in a `Store` class and there is a `subscript` which gets the item by `id`.  This is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can Help?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    struct Person: Identifiable {
        var id: Int
        var name: String
        var checkedIn: Bool
    }
    
    @State var people = [Person(id: 0, name: "George", checkedIn: false),
                         Person(id: 1, name: "Leah", checkedIn: true),
                         Person(id: 2, name: "Sarah", checkedIn: false)]
    
    @State private var selected = Set<Person.ID>()

    @State private var sortOrder = [KeyPathComparator(\Person.name)]

    
    private struct BoolComparator: SortComparator {
        typealias Compared = Bool

        func compare(_ lhs: Bool, _ rhs: Bool) -> ComparisonResult {
            switch (lhs, rhs) {
            case (true, false):
                return order == .forward ? .orderedDescending : .orderedAscending
            case (false, true):
                return order == .forward ? .orderedAscending : .orderedDescending
            default: return .orderedSame
            }
        }

        var order: SortOrder = .forward
    }

    var body: some View {
        Table(people, selection: $selected, sortOrder: $sortOrder) {
            TableColumn("Name", value: \.name)
            TableColumn("Checked In", value: \.checkedIn, comparator: BoolComparator()) { person in
                Toggle("Checked In", isOn: $people[people.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == person.id})!].checkedIn)
                    //.labelsHidden()
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: sortOrder) { newOrder in
            people.sort(using: newOrder)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```